# Unable to obtain username from WebAPI in ADFS4-OAuth2 OpenID

Tags: c#, oauth, adfs

I am trying to use ADFS Authentication with OAuth to communicate between my webapp and webapi. I am using ADFS4 and have configured application group with Server application and Webapi accordingly. I am trying to receive the userdetails, particularly the username from the webapi controller. Is it possible to pass the username details within the access token passed to webapi. Here is what I did from the Webapp side:

In the webapp controller after adfs authentication,

```
authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.authority, false);
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(Startup.clientId, Startup.appKey);
string accessToken = null; 
bool isAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; //return true
string username = User.Identity.Name; // returns username
string userId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value; // returns username

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
try
{
     result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Startup.apiResourceId, credential).Result;
     accessToken = result.AccessToken;

}
catch (AdalException ex)
{
}

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(Startup.apiResourceId + "/api/ConfApi").Result;
```

From the Webapi end, in Startup.Auth.cs, I have added these code

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
    app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication(
        new ActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            MetadataEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AdfsMetadataEndpoint"],
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
                SaveSigninToken = true,
                ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
            }
        });
    }
```

However, within the ConfApi controller, I cannot find any claims with user details.

What can I do to receive user details in the Webapi controller?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSIS9649: Received invalid OAuth request. The 'assertion' parameter value is not a valid access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867426/msis9649-received-invalid-oauth-request-the-assertion-parameter-value-is-not)

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually receiving the claims?

Did you configure claims rules for the web API on the ADFS side?

What did you use for Name - Given-Name, Display-Name etc?

Use something like Fiddler to monitor the traffic. After the OIDC authentication, you should see access tokens, id tokens etc.

Take the token and copy into jwt.io.

This will show you what you are actually receiving.

However, the OWIN classes translate the simple OAuth attributes e.g. "aud" into the claim type URI e.g. http://claims/this-claim so breakpoint and see what is in the claims collection and what type has been assigned to each.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer to this is the same answer to the question: [MSIS9649: Received invalid OAuth request. The 'assertion' parameter value is not a valid access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867426/msis9649-received-invalid-oauth-request-the-assertion-parameter-value-is-not)**

You have to use authorization code flow (instead of client credentials grant flow) to get the server app (web app in this case) to talk to the web API with the user's context.  Authorization code flow will pass the claims in the JWT Token.  Just make sure you pass thru any claims you need for the web API in the web API's RPT claim issuance transform rules.

[Vittorio has a nice post on authorization code flow, although it talks about azure.](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/29/using-adals-acquiretokenby-authorizationcode-to-call-a-web-api-from-a-web-app/)

In order to use authorization code flow, you need to handle the AuthorizationCodeReceived Event via Notifications on the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions from Startup.ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)

```c#
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
       ...
       Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {
           AuthorizationCodeReceived = async code => {
               ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(Startup.clientId, Startup.appKey);
               AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.authority, false);
               AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                   code.Code,
                   new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), 
                   credential, 
                   Startup.apiResourceId);
           }
       }
```

When you are ready to make the call you acquire your token silently.

```c#
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.authority, false);
var credential = new ClientCredential(Startup.clientId, Startup.appKey);
var claim = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
var userId = new UserIdentifier(claim, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);

result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(
    Startup.apiResourceId,
    credential,
    userId);

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "Bearer", 
    result.AccessToken);
```