# MSIS9649: Received invalid OAuth request. The 'assertion' parameter value is not a valid access token

Tags: oauth, openid, adfs

I am trying to implement ADFS4 - OAuth (OpenID connect) for authentication and webapp to webapi communication.

I have configured ADFS application group accordingly and use OpenIdconnectauth pipeline in webapp for authentication. In order to call webapi, if I request accesstoken using just client credential grant, it works fine as I receive the valid access token and able to get to the api. However, the access token does not have any user details in it which I need it from the webapi end.

So, then I tried by creating UserAssertion object from bootstrapcontext.token. But this time, when ever I request access token, I receive this error as mentioned in the title.

Here is the code snippet:

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
AuthenticationResult result = null;
authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.authority, false);
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(Startup.clientId, Startup.appKey);
string usercheck = User.Identity.Name; //For checking, returns username

var bootstrapContext = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext as System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext;
string username = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn) != null ? ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value : ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
string userAccessToken = bootstrapContext.Token;
UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(bootstrapContext.Token, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", username);

string accessToken = null;
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

try {
//result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Startup.apiResourceId, credential).Result; // This works fine but no user details in the token
 result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Startup.apiResourceId, credential, userAssertion).Result;
}
```

Here is how the Startup.ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) looks like in both webapp and webapi:

In webapp:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    AuthenticationType = OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,

                    MetadataAddress = metadataAddress,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                    RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        SaveSigninToken = true
                    },

                    ResponseType = "code id_token",
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                        {
                            context.HandleResponse();
                            context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
}
```

And in webapi:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
            app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication(
                new ActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    MetadataEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AdfsMetadataEndpoint"],
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
                        SaveSigninToken = true,
                        ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                    }
                });
        }
```

I reckon that the token that I am passing in to the userassertion is incorrect. But how can I fix this? Is there any other way which I can get the user details in to the access token. I really appreciate if anyone can help us to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use authorization code flow to get the MVC app to talk to the API.  [Vittorio has a nice post on it here, although it talks about azure.](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/29/using-adals-acquiretokenby-authorizationcode-to-call-a-web-api-from-a-web-app/)

In order to do that you need to handle the AuthorizationCodeReceived Event via Notifications on the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions from Startup.ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)

```c#
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
       ...
       Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {
           AuthorizationCodeReceived = async code => {
               ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(Startup.clientId, Startup.appKey);
               AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.authority, false);
               AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                   code.Code,
                   new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), 
                   credential, 
                   Startup.apiResourceId);
           }
       }
```

When you are ready to make the call you acquire your token silently.

```c#
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.authority, false);
var credential = new ClientCredential(Startup.clientId, Startup.appKey);
var claim = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
var userId = new UserIdentifier(claim, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);

result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(
    Startup.apiResourceId,
    credential,
    userId);

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "Bearer", 
    result.AccessToken);
```